# Retrieving Venue Information on Fourquare via Twitter Handle

Tags: foursquare

I am aware that Foursquare's /users/search works if you are searching a venue via its twitter handle. Is there is a way to achieve this through userless access?

Thanks for your help.

Deniz

Answer (score 0):

Nope, the users/search endpoint requires authentication: https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/users/search